# How to insert to different columns when using UNIQUE constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

[image]

Both car-model and motor-model have unique constraints.

I try to insert first all my car-models. so

```
Car-model
Volkwgen
Tesla
```

Then I want to add the motor-models

```
Motor-model
PX
GX
```

but due unique constraints I get [Null] values

even without unique constraints i get the [Null] value.

Comment: the id and name are not  related

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on car-model and motor-model, you cannot do what you want. You cannot insert all the car-model values, and then all to motor-model values, you need to insert both the car-model and motor-model at the same time.

Comment: is there any way to fix this? or it is impossible?

Comment: That looks like a really strange design. Without knowing what exactly those columns should represent, I would guess you need **two** tables: one for the car models and one for the motor models. And possibly a third that sets up the link between them.

Comment: Even without unique constraints is not possible to insert first all cars and then all motors. So it is imposible in Postgres!!

Comment: Which should give you a strong indication that you are using the wrong table design

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about how to insert data into a Postgres table.  You should ideally insert a complete record, all in one go, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (Id, name)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom'),
    (2, 'ALEX');
```

Regarding unique constraints, I'm not sure it is a good idea to have a unique constraint on the `name` column, because, after all, two people can and often do have the same name.  But making `ID` an identity primary key column is a good idea.

Comment: I use this table as exampel! but what i want is having two different coulumns each with uniqe constraints. where i can add tot coulmn 1 and also to column 2.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Please edit your question and tell us the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
insert into car_models (car_model, motor_model)
    values ('Volkswagen', 'PX'),
           ('Tesla', 'GX');
```